# Calculate Sum of Balance in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to produce a Customer Balance Outstanding Report.

I have two tables: `customer` and `transaction`:

**customer**

```
custid| custname
------+------------
1     | abc
2     | xyz 
3     | ben    
4     | angel
```

**transaction**

```
tid| customerid  | amount
---+-------------+-------
1  | 1           | 100
2  | 4           | 300
3  | 2           | 130
4  | 2           | 500
5  | 3           | 100
6  | 1           | 35
7  | 4           | 104
8  | 1           | 25
9  | 3           | 50
```

I want to get results like this:

```
Custname  | balance
----------+--------
abc       | 160
xyz       | 630
ben       | 150   
angel     | 404
```

Comment: Show us your code(SQL).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT a.custname as custname 
     , sum(b.amount) as balance 
  from customer a
     , transaction b 
 where a.custid = b.customerid
```

Comment: Note that aside from this being incorrect, we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992. Come. Join us.

Comment: @vivek_23 What you mean .?  Do you Know good example in my code?